# How to build and inspect MultipartFormData objects using Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core

This is a compound question so I will do my best to keep it specific to the title, but first the background:

For the purposes of this question, the Invoke-Web/Rest cmdlets will be called web-cmdlets.

I have a `[System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]` object. That contains a field.

I can build the object:

```
$MultipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()

#XML
$stringHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new("form-data")
$stringHeader.Name = "request"
$StringContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($xml, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/xml")
$StringContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $stringHeader
$multipartContent.Add($stringContent)
```

And pass it to the web-cmdlets with verbose logging, and I can see that the payload has data being sent along with the request. The server returns an error indicating it does not see any XML data, but it acknowledges the request. If it sees data and doesn't like the way it's formatted it will produce a different error.

These 2 behaviors indicate to me it's sending data, but it's sending it in a manner that makes it appear empty to the server.

If I explicitly use the `-Form` parameter and let the web-cmdlets handle the creation of the `[System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]`, the request is successful.

So I know that it should work, but I cannot determine what I'm doing that is different than using `-Form`. I've followed the directions by Mark Kraus: [Here](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/09/multipartform-data-support-for-invoke.html), who created this particular functionality, but I am unable to get this to work manually.

How does someone trace these cmdlets to dig deeper?

Example [A] - Using `-Form` that is successful.

```
$XMLStringObject = @"
<request>
<parameters>             
</parameters>                   
</request>  
"@

$Params = @{
    URI        = "https://URL.com/xml"
    Credential = $Credential
    Form       = @{"request" = $XMLStringObject }
    Method     = "Post"
}

Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

Comment: Why are you setting `Content-Disposition` on a request?  And form data is a content-type.  So do you need to send a form or XML?

Comment: Please see the edit, Example [A], for the working example using -Form. 

My assumption, which could be false, was that if the Form field took IDictionary value "request" it must be a form field that happens to take XML.

Comment: Yes.  A form field that happens to be XML is not an XML content-type.  Use Fiddler or similar to examine the request details. https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Adding quote literals to $stringheader.name has made for a successful submission on MacOS. see Example [B].  This is now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quote literals "" to the value of $stringHeader.name on the [ContentDispositionHeaderValue] object.

```
$XMLStringObject = @"
<request>
<parameters>             
</parameters>                   
</request>  
"@


$MultipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$stringHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new("form-data")
$stringHeader.Name = '"request"'
$StringContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($xml, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/xml")
$StringContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $stringHeader
$multipartContent.Add($stringContent)
```

[Related Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033535/multipartformdatacontent-add-stringcontent-is-adding-carraige-return-linefeed-to)

[Related Github - PR in web-cmdlet modules that adds quotes](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/09/multipartform-data-support-for-invoke.html)

You can view the text representation of the [MultipartFormDataContent] object that will be sent by calling. `ReadAsStringAsync()` on the object.

From the above code `$multipartContent.ReadAsStringAsync()` returns:

```
--f657665b-b82f-49b2-a67c-8ff35da8ea6c
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8                                         
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request"

<request>
<parameters>             
</parameters>                   
</request>                                                                         

--f657665b-b82f-49b2-a67c-8ff35da8ea6c--
```

In the original code, `name=request` was written without quotes, resulting in the behavior of the receiving server not recognizing the value of the field.

Once the syntax is corrected you can submit the [MultipartFormDataContent] object to the Body parameter of `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest`.
[Documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/6782/files/80c4a2c17b35f7620af43d3883d4b14ee24c73f1)

```
$Params = @{
    URI        = "https://URL.com/xml"
    Credential = $Credential
    Body       = $multipartContent
    Method     = "Post"
}

Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

If these changes didn't work, using Fiddler you can read the request to see if the object is being sent at all.

In my case, the above was correct, but one of my test functions was accidentally wrapping the [multiparFormDataContent] object, so instead of sending the textual representation, it would send just the literal name of the object "System.Net.Http.MultipartContent" (oops!)